# Accessing key name in key-value pairs on props object in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React app and want the component I'm working on to be able to access the key names in the props object the component is receiving.

For example, I have this object:

```
var fido = {
 animal: "dog",
 legs: 4,
 licksSelf: true
}
```

I then pass this object via the props object to my React component:

```
<Pet characteristics={fido} />
```

Then in my React component for Pet, I want to access both the key and the value, how might I do that? For example, in this following incorrect code:

```
class Pet extends React.Component {
 render () {
  var petList = this.props.characteristics.map((char) => {
   return (
    <div>{char.key} : {char.value}</div> // <-- what should this code look like?
   );
  };
   return (
    <div>{petList}</div>
   );
  };
};
```

Does anyone know how I access the names of the keys in the key-value pairs on the props object? Thanks!

Comment: well...first of all you cant map over an object. You can only map over an array

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I was trying to come up with a quick example and wasn't thinking. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method:

```
const petList = Object.entries(fido).map(([key,value])=>{
  return (
      <div>{key} : {value.toString()}</div>
  );
})
```

`value.toString()` for boolean types to render correctly